# How have prominent gurus explained the difference between Abrahamic gods and ishvara(bhagavan)?

Tags: gods, guru, other-religions

What is the difference between Abrahamic Gods like YHWH, Allah, and dharmic Gods like Vishnu and Shiva? How have gurus explained why you should not worship Abrahamic Gods and instead worship dharmic Gods? Is there any reason the dharmic supreme God will not accept the worship of the supreme God in general by practitioners of the Abrahamic faiths?

Comment: Besides being not related , the question is also too broad to answer in such forums entirely.

Comment: This is off topic because in order to answer this we need to know about the features of the Abrahamic gods you've mentioned and which we are not required to do here.

Comment: Abrahamic Gods are actually very similar to Indra, so it is basically a question of how Indra and Ishvara/Brahman are different. That question will also be on topic.

Comment: Please edit your q appropiately.